# How to locate 32 bit apps in iOS 13

Tags: applications, ios, 32-bit

I know that 32-bit applications do not run on iOS since iOS 11. Prior to iOS 13, attempting to start a 32-bit application resulted in an

> “This app” Needs To Be Updated

alert. Now the screen becomes black for some seconds, and then the lock screen (where you have to enter your code or Touch ID) appears.

So I thought this might be a good time to remove all remaining 32-bit apps from my device. But how to find them all? Prior to iOS 13, “Settings > General > About > Applications” listed all incompatible apps. That list does not exist anymore.

Is there an alternative method to list all 32-bit applications, so that I can delete them?

Comment: I don't know why Apple removed that feature from Settings, it's still valid.  I don't know of any other way to check for apps in iOS.  You might just need to launch them and see if they crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. It is not as convenient as the “Settings > General > About > Applications” list (which does not exist anymore), but allows to determine all 32-bit (or otherwise incompatible) apps without launching all installed apps and check if they crash:

- Open the “App Store” app and tap on the user profile icon:

[image]

- Select “Purchased”:

[image]

- Scroll through the app list. The incompatible ones have a grayed-out “Open” button:

[image]

Comment: Better/alternative solutions are still welcome!

Comment: Good workaround!

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, there is no way to identify if the app is 32-bit or 64 bit in iOS 13. But if you are annoyed by the error message that *“This app” Needs To Be Updated"* Often check the "What's new" panel in App store is the only suggestion I can suggest because apps need to be kept up to date in order to continue working when a new version of the operating system is released. For some old app and small developers, if there is no update version displayed as the picture point, it might be worth looking for an alternative or the one that you should delete.[image: App what's new in App store]

You have a further reading on [Which apps won't work in iOS 13?](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iosapps/apps-wont-work-ios-13-3660434/)

Comment: Perhaps I expressed myself badly. There is no *“This app Needs To Be Updated”* message anymore, the app just crashes. And unfortunately, those apps are no longer maintained. What I am looking for is a convenient method to find all installed 32-bit apps so that I can delete them (i.e. more convenient than launching all apps.)

Comment: hopefully, you find a better way to locate them. Great work!